# XCTAssert syntax error with array shorthand expression and method call

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xctest

So I am diving into unit tests with XCTest, and have run into a little problem.

When I write an XCTAssert statement with a shorthand array declaration and method call inside, a syntax error is spat out in Xcode:

```
XCTAssert([self hasStrings:@[ @"foo", @"bar" ]]);
```

In the Xcode compile errors:

```
Expected identifier or '('
```

However, if I add more brackets around the expression, it will work:

```
XCTAssert(([self hasStrings:@[ @"foo", @"bar" ]]));
```

Is this something to do with some of my syntax not being allowed to be passed into a macro? (Assuming that XCTAssert is a macro)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`XCTAssert` is a macro with a variable argument list:

```
#define XCTAssert(expression, format...) \
    _XCTPrimitiveAssertTrue(expression, ## format)
```

In your first form, the preprocessor interprets

```
[self hasStrings:@[ @"foo", @"bar" ]]
```

as *two* macro arguments, separated by a comma.

Comment: Wow, great answer! I had a similar problem using [NSArray arrayWithObjects: ... ] method inside XCTAssert(...) call. Thanks for clearing that out!